# How to reference module in declaration file

Tags: typescript

I've been searching for hours now and can't find a straight answer on this. I am creating a nodejs project which is using the node.d.ts declaration file.

I want to create a new declaration file in my project that will hold all the interfaces.

In this file 'Controller.d.ts' I have the following:

```
/// <reference path="./interfaces/node.d.ts" />
import http = require( "http" );

interface IController
{
    processRequest( request: http.ServerRequest, response: http.ServerResponse, queryData: any );
}
```

However by using the import statement in the declaration file, none of the ts files recognise IController. Only if I remove the import does it work. But if I remove the import then the Controller.d.ts file is incorrect as it doesn't know what the "http" module is.

How can I reference the http module in my declaration file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Controller.d.ts` to export `IController` like so:

```
import http = require("http");

interface IController {
    processRequest( request: http.ServerRequest, response: http.ServerResponse, queryData: any );
}

export = IController;
```

Then in your application's typescript file, reference `Controller.d.ts` by doing this (change the path if necessary):

```
import IController = require("./Controller");
```

Now you can reference `IController`.